# alignat: removing the gap between the aligned variable and its coefficient

Tags: align, alignat

For the second equation, how can I remove the space between the aligned `\dot{x}_1` and its coefficient without abusing extra ampersands?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
    \dot{v}_1 &= -\frac{k}{M_1} x_1 - \frac{d_1+d_2}{M_1} &&\dot{x}_1 + \frac{d_2}{M_1} &&\dot{x}_2\\
    %
    \dot{v}_2 &= \frac{d_2}{M_2} &&\dot{x}_1 - \frac{d_2}{M_2} &&\dot{x}_2 + \frac{f}{M_2}
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By *its coefficient* do you mean `\frac{d_2}{M_2}`?

Comment: @Sigur Yes.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
    \dot{v}_1 &= -\frac{k}{M_1} x_1 - &\frac{d_1+d_2}{M_1} &\dot{x}_1 + \frac{d_2}{M_1} &&\dot{x}_2\\
    %
    \dot{v}_2 &= &\frac{d_2}{M_2} &\dot{x}_1 - \frac{d_2}{M_2} &&\dot{x}_2 + \frac{f}{M_2}
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know it is a very basic question, but could you please tell me what is the difference between adding `&&` and a single one `&`?

Comment: @Diaa the alignments are like `tabular` (it is the same tex `\halign` command underneath) so it is a sequence of columns and `x&&` puts x in one column followed by a blank entry and `&&x` has a blank entry in one cell followed by x. the alignment is like `\begin{tabular}{rlrlrlrlrlrlrlrlrlr}`  so entries are left or right aligned depending which column they are in.

Comment: I highly appreciate your patience and consideration.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, and what is the meaning of `{3}` ?

Comment: @Sigur it is the number of `rl` pairs in the alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, so `{3}` produces six columns?

Comment: @Sigur hey good mathematics, yes 2*3=6:-)  the idea is that it's 3 parallel equations each taking up a `lhs&rhs` pair with a `&` between them so `{3} == up to 5 `&`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, not it is clear to me... I'm not good in math... lol

Answer (score 1):

I propose one of these three variants – the last one with an extra pair of `&`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{3}
    \dot{v}_1 &= -\frac{k}{M_1} x_1 &{} - \frac{d_1+d_2}{M_1}&\dot{x}_1 + \frac{d_2}{M_1} &&\dot{x}_2\\
    %
    \dot{v}_2 &= &\frac{d_2}{M_2}&\dot{x}_1 - \frac{d_2}{M_2} &&\dot{x}_2 + \frac{f}{M_2}
    \end{alignat*}

    \begin{alignat*}{3}
    \dot{v}_1 &= -\frac{k}{M_1} x_1 - {}& \frac{d_1+d_2}{M_1}&\dot{x}_1 + \frac{d_2}{M_1} &&\dot{x}_2\\
    %
    \dot{v}_2 &=\phantom{-} \frac{f}{M_2} +{} &\frac{d_2}{M_2}&\dot{x}_1 - \frac{d_2}{M_2} &&\dot{x}_2
    \end{alignat*}

    \begin{alignat*}{4}
    \dot{v}_1 &= -\frac{k}{M_1} x_1 & &{}- {}& \frac{d_1+d_2}{M_1}&\dot{x}_1 + \frac{d_2}{M_1} &&\dot{x}_2\\
    %
    \dot{v}_2 &=\phantom{-} \frac{f}{M_2} & & {} +{} &\frac{d_2}{M_2}&\dot{x}_1 - \frac{d_2}{M_2} &&\dot{x}_2
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]